# How do I create a line chart that uses a table as a datasource?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, linechart

The OpenXML SDK Productivity tool is no doubt extremely useful, however
creating a line chart in open XML which refers to a table with six cells results in 8000 generated lines of code.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this seemingly simple thing:

1. Create a chart
2. Link the chart to a table within the same excel file using a formula like `x1=Table1[Date], y1=Table1[Temp1], x2=Table1[Date], y2=Table1[Temp2]`

I've re-factored a lot of this code generated by the OpenXMLSDK tool it in an attempt to make a simple method: Pass it as many formulas/series referring to the table/cells containing your data as you want.

It works, **however there's still a lot of generated code, it's still very ugly, convulted and a work in progress**. If you improve it, feel free to post your changes.

Sample Usage:

1. Generate code from an excel file using the OpenXML SDK productivity tool. Create a new table in the file named Table1 with the columns "Time", "Temp 1" and "Temp 2". Do not insert a chart.
2. Paste the below code at the end of the "CreateParts" method:

   ```
   using C = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts;
   C.Marker marker3 = OpenXMLUtils.CreateMarker(C.MarkerStyleValues.Circle, 5, A.SchemeColorValues.Accent1);
   C.Marker marker2 = OpenXMLUtils.CreateMarker(C.MarkerStyleValues.Circle, 5, A.SchemeColorValues.Accent2);
   C.ScatterChartSeries scatterChartSeries1 = OpenXMLUtils.CreateSeries(0U, "Table1[Time]", "Table1[Temp 1]", marker3);
   C.ScatterChartSeries scatterChartSeries2 = OpenXMLUtils.CreateSeries(1U, "Table1[Time]", "Table1[Temp 2]", marker2);

   OpenXMLUtils.CreateChartSheet(workbookPart1, 2U, "Chart Sheet", scatterChartSeries1, scatterChartSeries2);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The code is too long to paste here.
I've added a link:
http://pastebin.com/63XKknxx

Here are the important parts:

```
public static C.ValueAxis CreateAxis(C.ScatterChart chart, UInt32Value id, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.AxisPositionValues position)
{
    chart.Append(new C.AxisId() { Val = id });

    C.ValueAxis valueAxis = new C.ValueAxis();
    C.AxisId axisID = new C.AxisId() { Val = id };
    C.Scaling scaling = new C.Scaling();
    C.Orientation orientation = new C.Orientation() { Val = C.OrientationValues.MinMax };
    scaling.Append(orientation);
    C.Delete deleteProperty = new C.Delete() { Val = false };
    C.AxisPosition axisPosition = new C.AxisPosition() { Val = position };


    C.MajorGridlines majorGridlines = new C.MajorGridlines(
            new C.ChartShapeProperties(
                new A.Outline(new A.SolidFill(
                    new A.SchemeColor(
                        new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 50000 },
                        new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 50000 }
                    ) { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Text1 }
                ))
            )
    );

    C.CrossingAxis crossingAxis = new C.CrossingAxis() { Val = id };
    valueAxis.Append(axisID);
    valueAxis.Append(scaling);
    valueAxis.Append(deleteProperty);
    valueAxis.Append(axisPosition);
    valueAxis.Append(majorGridlines);
    valueAxis.Append(crossingAxis);
    return valueAxis;
}

private static void CreateChart(ChartPart chartPart, params C.ScatterChartSeries[] series)
{
    C.ChartSpace chartSpace = new C.ChartSpace();
    chartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
    chartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
    chartSpace.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
    C.Date1904 date19041 = new C.Date1904() { Val = false };


    AlternateContentChoice alternateContentChoice2 = new AlternateContentChoice() { Requires = "c14" };
    alternateContentChoice2.AddNamespaceDeclaration("c14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart");
    C14.Style style1 = new C14.Style() { Val = 102 };

    alternateContentChoice2.Append(style1);

    AlternateContentFallback alternateContentFallback1 = new AlternateContentFallback();
    C.Style style2 = new C.Style() { Val = 2 };

    alternateContentFallback1.Append(style2);


    C.Chart mainChart = new C.Chart();

    C.Title chartTitle = new C.Title();
    C.Layout layout1 = new C.Layout();
    C.Overlay overlay1 = new C.Overlay() { Val = false };

    C.ChartShapeProperties chartShapeProperties1 = new C.ChartShapeProperties();
    A.NoFill noFill1 = new A.NoFill();

    A.Outline outline4 = new A.Outline();
    A.NoFill noFill2 = new A.NoFill();

    outline4.Append(noFill2);
    A.EffectList effectList4 = new A.EffectList();

    chartShapeProperties1.Append(noFill1);
    chartShapeProperties1.Append(outline4);
    chartShapeProperties1.Append(effectList4);

    C.TextProperties textProperties1 = new C.TextProperties();
    A.BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new A.BodyProperties() { Rotation = 0, UseParagraphSpacing = true, VerticalOverflow = A.TextVerticalOverflowValues.Ellipsis, Vertical = A.TextVerticalValues.Horizontal, Wrap = A.TextWrappingValues.Square, Anchor = A.TextAnchoringTypeValues.Center, AnchorCenter = true };
    A.ListStyle listStyle1 = new A.ListStyle();

    A.Paragraph paragraph1 = new A.Paragraph();

    A.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new A.ParagraphProperties();

    A.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties1 = new A.DefaultRunProperties() { FontSize = 1400, Bold = false, Italic = false, Underline = A.TextUnderlineValues.None, Strike = A.TextStrikeValues.NoStrike, Kerning = 1200, Spacing = 0, Baseline = 0 };

    A.SolidFill solidFill7 = new A.SolidFill();

    A.SchemeColor schemeColor16 = new A.SchemeColor() { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Text1 };
    A.LuminanceModulation luminanceModulation9 = new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 65000 };
    A.LuminanceOffset luminanceOffset1 = new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 35000 };

    schemeColor16.Append(luminanceModulation9);
    schemeColor16.Append(luminanceOffset1);

    solidFill7.Append(schemeColor16);
    A.LatinFont latinFont3 = new A.LatinFont() { Typeface = "+mn-lt" };
    A.EastAsianFont eastAsianFont3 = new A.EastAsianFont() { Typeface = "+mn-ea" };
    A.ComplexScriptFont complexScriptFont3 = new A.ComplexScriptFont() { Typeface = "+mn-cs" };

    defaultRunProperties1.Append(solidFill7);
    defaultRunProperties1.Append(latinFont3);
    defaultRunProperties1.Append(eastAsianFont3);
    defaultRunProperties1.Append(complexScriptFont3);

    paragraphProperties1.Append(defaultRunProperties1);
    A.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties1 = new A.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US" };

    paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
    paragraph1.Append(endParagraphRunProperties1);

    textProperties1.Append(bodyProperties1);
    textProperties1.Append(listStyle1);
    textProperties1.Append(paragraph1);

    chartTitle.Append(layout1);
    chartTitle.Append(overlay1);
    chartTitle.Append(chartShapeProperties1);
    chartTitle.Append(textProperties1);

    C.PlotArea plotArea1 = new C.PlotArea();

    C.ScatterChart scatterChart1 = new C.ScatterChart();
    C.ScatterStyle scatterStyle1 = new C.ScatterStyle() { Val = C.ScatterStyleValues.LineMarker };
    C.VaryColors varyColors1 = new C.VaryColors() { Val = false };




    scatterChart1.Append(scatterStyle1);
    scatterChart1.Append(varyColors1);


    //DS (Modified): <<

    foreach (var cSeries in series)
    {
        scatterChart1.Append(cSeries);
    }

    scatterChart1.Append(new C.DataLabels(
        new C.Delete() { Val = true }
    ));

    C.ValueAxis valueAxis1 = CreateAxis(scatterChart1, 1848291296U, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.AxisPositionValues.Bottom);
    C.ValueAxis valueAxis2 = CreateAxis(scatterChart1, 1848283680U, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.AxisPositionValues.Left);

    //>>

    plotArea1.Append(scatterChart1);
    plotArea1.Append(valueAxis1);
    plotArea1.Append(valueAxis2);

    mainChart.Append(chartTitle);
    mainChart.Append(plotArea1);


    chartSpace.Append(date19041);
    chartSpace.Append(mainChart);
    chartPart.ChartSpace = chartSpace;
}

public static C.ScatterChartSeries CreateSeries(UInt32Value index, string xFormula, string yFormula, C.Marker marker)
{
    C.ScatterChartSeries scatterChartSeries2 = new C.ScatterChartSeries(
        new C.Index() { Val = index },
        new C.Order() { Val = index }
    );
    scatterChartSeries2.Append(marker);

    scatterChartSeries2.Append(
        new C.XValues(
        new C.NumberReference(
                new C.Formula(xFormula)
        )),

        new C.YValues(
        new C.NumberReference(
                new C.Formula(yFormula)
        ))
    );

    scatterChartSeries2.Append(new C.Smooth() { Val = false });
    return scatterChartSeries2;
}

public static C.Marker CreateMarker(C.MarkerStyleValues makerStyle, ByteValue size, A.SchemeColorValues markerColor)
{

    return new C.Marker(
        new C.Symbol() { Val = makerStyle },
        new C.Size() { Val = size },
        new C.ChartShapeProperties(
            new A.SolidFill(
                    new A.SchemeColor() { Val = markerColor }
                ),
                new A.Outline(
                    new A.SolidFill(
                        new A.SchemeColor() { Val = markerColor }
                    )
                ) { Width = 9525 }
        )
    );
}
```